# data mining cluster in Non-Euclidean Spaces

Tags: cluster-computing, data-mining

Consider the space of strings with edit distance as the distance
measure. Give an example of a set of strings such that if we choose the clustroid
by minimizing the sum of the distances to the other points we get one point
as the clustroid, but if we choose the clustroid by minimizing the maximum
distance to the other points, another point becomes the clustroid.

I meet the challenge of this topic. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What you have tried till now

Answer (score 0):

Try this set of strings:

```
badger
badger
badger
badger
badger
banana
nanana
```

What string has the minimum sum, what string the smallest maximum distance?

Comment: given a `set` of string, so the 5 badger is actually not example actually. In distance space, if distance = 0 mean A is B.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Anony-Mousse's answer, I think I would give this:
backer
bacher
bacfer
bacper
bacjer
banono
kanono